# Duke Record Linkage Configuration XML

Tags: xml, record-linkage, duke

i've a problem with this record linkage: I have this two csv files and the perfect mapping, i've used this configuration but Duke give me always 0 link found. Perhaps i've selected wrong thresholds?
Someone can help me?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/m80eub51ng7iz5o/help.zip?dl=0

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please write your a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so people can help you more.